# Is it possible to check for global variables in IPython when running a file?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a file like so:

```
import pandas a pd

def a_func():
    print 'doing stuff'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if 'data' not in globals():
        print 'loading data...'
        data = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
```

When I run the file in IPython with `run file.py`, it always loads the data, but when I print `globals.keys()` in IPython, I can see the `data` variable.  Is there a way to access the global variables from IPython from within my `file.py` script, so I don't have to load the data every time I run the script in IPython?

Comment: IPython normally creates a new namespace for each file you `%run`, and then transfers the variables into your interactive namespace afterwards. If you really want to run files directly in the interactive namespace, `%run -i` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a python file is executed the globals() dictionary is reset by the interpreter. So if you will try to do something like

```
print globals().keys()
```

you can see that 'data' is not in globals. This dictionary gets updated as the program runs. So I don't think you can refer to the globals() of the IPython in the program.

check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other) ,according to it, globals are emptied.

Comment: I think with IPython, it's putting a empty/None assigned `data` in global scope preemptively (even if the specific line hasn't been/never will be run).

Comment: check this link https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other, according to it it empty globals.

Comment: Yeah, been using Python for a bit over a decade but was trying to understand why the person asking the question would think `data` was in globals().   Just tested it and Cpy2 does not pre-assign globals so moot point.